# Issue with Windowless WPF windows in a VSTO project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vsto

I have a windowless wpf window that works fine in a wpf project

Now while showing that window from a VSTO project, the border, caption and close button are shown

Any help on why and how to fix this ?

thanks

Comment: It could be a security thing, Office doesn't want external devs creating windows that the user cannot see or interact with, so it forces your window to have the attributes you are seeing.